# Create our own field with transaction data in privatenet

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, private-blockchain, myetherwallet, explorers

I know we have 'data' field to add any comments but is it possible to add our own field based on the application ie; a field like 'purchased products' which will have purchased products of a user along with transaction data in privatenet?

Comment: But no one has answered yet...:(

Answer (score 0):

Using web3.js you can use sendTransaction(). For example with the geth console:

```
geth attach geth.ipc
> web3.eth.sendTransaction({
    from: web3.eth.coinbase,
    to: toAddress,
    value: web3.toWei(ethers),
    data: web3.toHex("My comment")
  })
```

Replace `toAddress` with desired receipient, `ethers` with number of ethers to send, and `"My comment"` with the comment you want.

See https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction for details.

Comment: Instead of passing comment in 'data' field . Can we create a new field with new name?

Comment: What if I need to add a custom field along with transaction details when a function call from contract is done?